# How to replace Thread.Sleep ()? While all the elements are loaded

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to replace Thread.Sleep ()? While all the elements are loaded

```
public void Test()
{
    home.OpenHomePage();
    users.Login(new Logins("test1", "test2"));
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    BtnOk();
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
   ..................}
```

For example:
`BtnOk ();` 
before this, I wait until the element is loaded:
(`driver.FindElement (By.XPath ("// button")). Click ()`

Answer (score 0):

Stop using Thread.sleep() as it delays the execution even when the next element loads. Switch to Explicit waits.
As in your case, the following wait can be used :

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.XPath ("// button")));
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your question/code block before the function `BtnOk()` to check for the *WebElement* to be *clickable* and to invoke `Click()` on it you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_WebDriverWait.htm) with [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm) as [ElementToBeClickable](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementToBeClickable.htm) as follows :

```
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("// button")));
element.Click();
```